# Identifying correct cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, substitution-cipher, vigenere

I am trying to decrypt a text(~900 characters) and I started with the *assumption* that its a Vigenère cipher as the one of the identifier tool identified it as Vigenère cipher and also the Index of Coincidence (IOC) for the ciphertext is 0.04492. So I used another tool to check the IOC values for different key lengths (up to 20) but I see the IOC for all the key lengths is not anywhere close to 0.06 which is typically the case for every piece of Vigenère ciphered text I have seen. And in my case, the IOC for all the key length (up to 20) is around 0.045. I think this means either of the two things

- The key length is greater than 20 and I need to manually somehow compute the IOC for values > 20 as most of the tools available only offer key lengths up to 20
- this is not a Vigenère cipher at all, in that case, I don't even know how to proceed in terms of identifying the correct cipher.
  Any advice will be appreciated
  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Is this homework or a CTF?

Comment: thanks, its not a homework, its a puzzle posted on a quant trading firm website